# How to get rid of inconsistent behavior between running with debugger and not for a exception catching method

Tags: c#, debugging

I have created a method like NUnit's `Throws` method.
Basically, the method should return true if the action it's acting on will cause an exception of type `T` or any derived exception type, which is passed as a generic argument.

```
 Action a = () => Throw(new DerivedException());
 if(!a.Throws<BaseException>())
      throw new Exception("catastrophic error");
```

I have a helper `Throw` method that just throws an exception of a given type.
The `DerivedException` class derives from the `BaseException` class, which in turn derives from the `Exception` class.

The problem is that the behavior of the `Throws` method varies depending on whether or not the debugger is attached.  If the debugger is not attached, the method does what I would expect it to do.  When the debugger is attached though, it doesn't catch the `DerivedException` as a `BaseException`, but instead catches it as an `Exception`.

Here's the code to reproduce (which can go in a console application project file.):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Action a = () => Throw(new DerivedException());
            if (!a.Throws<BaseException>())
                throw new Exception("catastrophic error.");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("wow, you must not have been debugging.");
        }
        private static void Throw<T>(T exc) where T : Exception
        {
            throw exc;
        }
    }

    public static partial class ExtensionMethods
    {
        public static bool Throws<T>(this Action action) where T : Exception
        {
            try
            {
                action.Invoke();
            }
            catch (T)
            {
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.GetType());
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }

    }


    public class BaseException : Exception
    {
    }
    public class DerivedException : BaseException
    {
    }



}
```

Hit F5 (debug) and it doesn't properly catch the `DerivedException`.
Hit Ctrl+F5 (no debugging) and it works fine, catching the `DerivedException` as a `BaseException`.

Can someone please explain the discrepancy?  Thanks.

**UPDATE**
I am running VS 2008 Professional Edition, with Version 3.5 SP1 of the .NET Framework.  Apparently this is not an issue for later versions.  Thanks everyone who tried this.

Comment: Any reason you're not using [Assert.Throws](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=exceptionAsserts&r=2.5.10)?

Comment: What does the "first chance" message say in the Output window?

Comment: @TrueWill: I'm using an old version of NUnit and sometimes I like to do things myself.  Do you see anything wrong w/ my implementation?

Comment: Hmm, that's wrong.  You're throwing a DerivedException.  Very hard to come up with a scenario where the debugger causes this wrong exception to be thrown *and* not to be caught.  There's a bug somewhere but I don't see it.  Do make sure that these exception types are not defined in multiple assemblies.

Comment: @HansPassant: Ugh, really sorry.  The thing that is thrown in the output window is derived exception.

Comment: @HansPassant: You were right. The exceptions were created across assemblies.  Although it's still not clear to me why that would affect the attached debugging mode and not regular unit testing.

Comment: Well, I tried it again with the classes defined in the same assembly, and had the same unusual behavior.

Comment: I always get "wow, you must not have been debugging", even under a debugger, and even when stepping into every single line. I'm using VS2010 SP1 on an x64 machine with Any CPU.

Comment: @AllonGuralnek: I am using Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition on an XP machine.  I guess they must have fixed the problem in later versions of VS.  Thank you for checking.

Comment: @user420667: Make sure you have all the latest service packs and extra QFEs installed.

Comment: @svick: Thanks for checking as well.  I am running .NET 3.5 SP1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess technically the answer here is to upgrade to a newer version of Visual Studio, i.e. 2010 or later.